# Spark Dataframe Joins - Select data present in first dataframe only

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes DF1 and DF2. My task is to select the data which is present is only in DF1 but not present in DF2. Could any1 please help. 
I'm using Spark 1.6 shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
val dfResult = df1.except(df2)
```

Note that the two dataframes need to have the same structure (same columns)

In Spark 2.0 you can do `ANTI JOIN`. Assume your records are identified by the common column `id` :

```
val dfResult = df1.join(df2, Seq("id"), "leftanti")
```

Comment: That's a very cool feature. Unfortunately I'm looking for a solution in Spark 1.6 shell.

Answer (score 0):

Spark provides several Join types, among them **leftsemi** you can use, this is similar to inner join difference being leftsemi join returns all columns from the left dataset and ignores all columns from the right dataset.

You can try something like the below in Scala to [Join Spark DataFrame using leftsemi join](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-dataframe-join/) types.

```
empDF.join(deptDF,empDF("emp_dept_id") ===  deptDF("dept_id"),"leftsemi")
    .show(false)
```

For Python use below [PySpark SQL join](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples/) dataframe example using leftsemi

```
empDF.join(deptDF,empDF.emp_dept_id ==  deptDF.dept_id,"leftsemi") \
   .show(truncate=False)
```

Alternatively, you can also use **left_semi**

Answer (score -1):

How about.. `dataframe1.as("d1").join(dataframe2.as("d2"), $"d1.col1" === $"d2.col1").select($"d1.*")` where col1 is the column to join.

Comment: Wouldn't that give me that data from Df1 which matches that data from DF2. ??

I'm looking for the data in DF1 which is NOT Present in DF2.